# Expand escape sequences detected by flex

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

In my scanner.lex file I have this:

`{Some rule that matches strings}    return STRING; //STRING is enum`

in my c++ file I have this:

```
if (yylex == STRING) {
    cout << "STRING: " << yytext << endl;
```

Obviously with some logic to take the input from stdin.
Now if this program gets the input "Hello\nWorld", my output is `"STRING: Hello\nWorld"`, while I would want my output to be:

```
Hello
World
```

The same goes for other escape characters such as `\"`,`\0`, `\x<hex_number>`, `\t`, `\\`... But I'm not sure how to achieve this. I'm not even sure if that's a flex issue or if I can solve this using only c++ tools...

How can I get this done?

Comment: There must be plenty of examples on how to use flex to parse C-like strings with escape sequences. Including the flex documentation itself IIRC.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in the documentation they're suggesting to use specific rules for each escape character and append the yytext content of each rule to a buffer. I was wondering if there's a more elegant way (perhaps somehow convert the output string I receive to a string that expands these characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) mentions in a comment, there is an [an example of how to do this using start conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html#index-matching-C_002dstyle-double_002dquoted-strings) in the Flex documentation. That example puts the escaping rules into a separate start condition; each rule is implemented by appending the unescaped text to a buffer. And that's the way it's normally done.

Of course, you might find an external library which unescapes C-style escaped strings, which you could call on the string returned by flex. But that would be both slower and less flexible than the approach suggested in the Flex manual: slower because it requires a second scan of the string, and less flexible because the library is likely to have its own idea of what escapes to handle.

If you're using C++, you might find it more elegant to modify that example to use a `std::string` buffer instead of an arbitrary fixed-size character array. You can compile a flex-generated scanner with C++, so there is no problem using C++ standard library objects in your scanner code.

Depending on the various semantic value types you are managing, you will probably want to modify the `yylex` prototype to either use an additional reference parameter or a more structured return type, in order to return the token value to the caller. Note that while it is OK to use `yytext` before the next call to `yylex`, it's not generally considered good style since it won't work with most parsers: in general, parsers require the ability to look one or more tokens ahead, and thus `yytext` is likely to be overwritten by the time your parser needs its value. [The flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html) documents the macro hook used to modify the `yylex()` prototype.